# An error: python code to make an decision tree

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

df = pd.read_csv('Monthly_COVID.csv')

target_column = 'Date'

feature_columns = ['State', 'COVID-19 Death']

X = df[feature_columns]
y = df[target_column]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

with this csv file.[image]

and I got

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-60f0ddaabcd5> in <cell line: 21>()
     19 model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
     20 
---> 21 model.fit(X_train, y_train)
     22 
     23 y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Connecticut'
```

I tried changing target_column and feature_columns,and searched about Connecticut, but could not solve it.
is that target_column and feature_columns problem?
should I change some?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: You will not solve this problem by researching about "Connecticut". It is the name of a US state which is part of your data. It is not a programming term.

Answer (score 1):

Nodes in a decision tree need to decide on numerical values.

Some scikit models can handle categorical data by automatically applying label encoding, i.e., they use the [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html?highlight=encode#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder) or the OrdinalEncoder.
However, making a decision on `state < 15` does not make sense - this is what the DecisionTreeClassifier does.

---

You have **categorical data**, where there is no ordering.
You have to use **one-hot encoding** e.g. a node needs to decide if:
`state_Alabama -> True | False?` for *every* state.

For that that you have to exchange your state column with with the once created by [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder) or [`pd.get_dummies(df, columns=["State"])`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)